# Custom Partitioner in Scala for RDD is not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark

I define a spark partitioner and want it to partition data by key,in my sample,the result data should be three different file(not null and their key are "aaa","aa" and "a"),but the reslut only two part

```
class Mypartitioner2( num:Int) extends org.apache.spark.Partitioner{
      override def numPartitions: Int = num

      override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
          if(key.toString.size ==3){
                  2
              }
          if(key.toString.size ==2){
                  1
             }
          else {
                  0
             }
    }
 }

object PersonalPartitioner {
     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
         val spark =SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
         val sc =spark.sparkContext
         val data =sc.parallelize(Array(
          ("aaa",2),("aaa",3),("aaa",1),("aaa",0),("aaa",4),
          ("aa",2),("aa",3),("aa",1),("aa",0),("aa",4),
          ("a",2),("a",3),("a",1),("a",0),("a",4) ))
         data.partitionBy(new Mypartitioner2(3)).saveAsTextFile("develop/wangdaopeng/lab4")
   }
   }
```

but the result is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvoJl.png)

key of “aaa” and "a" was in the same partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clause "else" missed in "Mypartitioner2" between two "if"s.

Comment: OK, root cause is this but the return approach also works. By definition.